# Selecting mysql record from python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I'm trying to set commands for updating and deleting records in a mysql database from a tkinter python gui. I copied the commands straight from a youtube tutorial that uses the same libraries that I'm using yet they don't work. The terminal throws me this error: "mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'oid' in 'where clause'"

Here I let my code, I apologyze for the spanish, I tried seeking answers in the spanish SO but haven´t got an answer. Please if anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong I would apreciate.

```
def borrar_registro():
    
    conn=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",
        user="root",
        password="Baelca1", database="Lista_datos_Baelca")
    cursor1=conn.cursor() 
    cursor1.execute('''DELETE FROM ticket WHERE oid='''+indice)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

```
#función modificar registro
def modificar_registro():
     
    conn=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",
        user="root",
        password="Baelca1", database="Lista_datos_Baelca")
    cursor1=conn.cursor()   
    comando="""UPDATE ticket SET Numero_guia = %s, Peso_guia = %s, Producto = %s, Transporte= %s, Proveedor = %s, Despacho = %s, Observaciones = %s WHERE oid= %s""" 
    entradas=  (entry_numeroguia.get(), entry_pesoguia.get(), entrada_producto.get(), entrada_transporte.get(), entrada_prov_cli.get(), entrada_destino.get(), entrada_observaciones.get(), indice)
    cursor1.execute(comando, entradas)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Note: "indice" is the index from the treeview, "oid" is suposed to get the treeview index and match it to the table index.

Comment: This does not appear to be a `tkinter` question

Comment: I'm pulling the data from a tkinter treeview, I didn't include it because treeviews are too long. The problem is in the "comando" lines. So I'll remove the tkinter tags but please don´t take down the question

Answer (score 0):

in this snippet

```
def borrar_registro():
    
    conn=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",
        user="root",
        password="Baelca1", database="Lista_datos_Baelca")
    cursor1=conn.cursor() 
    cursor1.execute('''DELETE FROM ticket WHERE oid='''+indice)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

you cannot directly add the string within the query. Parameterized queries have special formatting. The correct syntax would be:

```
cursor1.execute("DELETE FROM ticket WHERE oid=%s"%(indice,))
```

Try this approach in the second snippet as well. It will get longer but you can get sure that it is working and you can optimize it later.

Comment: also, since it is mostly Spanish I couldn't understand whether or not `indice` is a string or a number. However if `indice` is a string enclose `%s` within quotes `'%s'`